# Is it possible to change the css property of anchor tag

Tags: asp.net, css

I have been using asp:Menu control and in 2.0 it renders as table and collection of anchor tag. I can't use display block property display is inline for anchor tag. Has anyone been able to change it?

Comment: Please show some of the code you are working with and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in css you can write code like this:

```
table a {
    display: block; or inline;
    \\ you can add any attribute that you want. 
}
```

It applies the style on all `<a>` tags inside a table.

Comment: This is the right technique, but you might want wrap the asp:menu in its own `<div id="menuBox">` tag so that you may use
`#menuBox a` instead of `table a`. The css rule @Ahsan creates will apply to any and all anchors inside any and all tables on the page. By wrapping it in an identifiable div (id="...") you isolate the css to those particular anchor tags inside the menu box

Answer (score 0):

An anchor tag, if i'm understanding your question correctly, is simply an a tag.

You can style it several ways:
- with a class/id, which makes use of css's speed:

```
a.anchorClass {
 display: block;
 color: red;
 ... ... ...
}
```

- or with javascript after page load, you can get the element and apply css styles to it.

With jquery this is very easy:

```
$('a.anchorClass').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a { display: block !important;}
```

That should override any other declaration.